# ActiveX Control giving error with Office 2010

Tags: asp-classic, activex

We have a legacy classic ASP Website in our organization. Website uses lot of ActiveX controls. 
Recently we have upgraded our systems with Office 2010 from office 2007. 
Which has stopped these controls, actually all controls are giving some alert message. 
If we install office 2007 again, it works fine.

Is there any way we can debug or can see which component/part of activeX control is causing this issue.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. -- Nitin

DETAIL - http://forums.iis.net/post/2069115.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you should post your error messages and the calls you use to access the Office programs.

Comment: Error Message - 545 - An error Occured whil eloading the data at LINE 16. Detailed Description: Unable to bind to field or DataMember: 'c1'

Comment: Detail - http://forums.iis.net/post/2069115.aspx

Comment: There's always more than one way to skin the proverbial cat. Your ActiveX objects just probably don't work with Office 2010 end of story.  To that end you could try [somehting like this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1735/classic_asp_generate_excel_spreadsheets/).